# Scipy.loadmat() ---- SystemError: ../Objects/stringobject.c:3899: bad argument to internal function

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to load a .mat file into python that is quite large ( >75MB) and I am getting the following error. Can this be helped?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prop_keys.py", line 34, in <module>
    prop_d = scipy.io.loadmat(prop)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/io/matlab/mio.py", line 175, in loadmat
    matfile_dict = MR.get_variables(variable_names)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/io/matlab/mio5.py", line 272, in get_variables
    hdr, next_position = self.read_var_header()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/io/matlab/mio5.py", line 224, in read_var_header
    stream = BytesIO(dcor.decompress(data))
SystemError: ../Objects/stringobject.c:3899: bad argument to internal function
```

Comment: Impossible to debug without having access to this specific matlab file, please make it available for download somewhere. In general, there is no problem with loading large matlab files.

Comment: I've uploaded the file to Google Drive.

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwitLOvMDE9KZ2JaaEdrZ3FCMlk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please file a bug report: http://projects.scipy.org/scipy/ --- I don't have the time to look at this now

Answer (score 0):

As noted here: http://projects.scipy.org/scipy/ticket/1894

The file contains compressed data which blows up to 1.1GB when uncompressed.
The error message is a symptom of your machine not having enough free memory to store this data. In addition to this, the latter part of the file seems also corrupted and cannot be correctly loaded by Matlab either.

(Scipy's mat-file loading routines actually require 2x memory if the data is compressed; however, this will be fixed in Scipy 0.13.0.)